# How do I add an event to another users calendar in Office 365 using PHP?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph and wish to give users the ability to add items to other users calendar though a an app we are writing.

I am using the following code, and can add to my own calendar.

```
$subject = 'Subject';
$body = 'Body content';
$start = time();
$end = time() + (30 * 60);
$startStr = date('Y-m-d', $start) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $start) . ".0000000";
$endStr = date('Y-m-d', $end) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', $end) . ".0000000";

$data = array();
$data['subject'] = $subject;
$data['body'] =  array();
$data['body']['content'] = $body;
$data['start'] = array();
$data['start']['dateTime'] = $startStr;
$data['start']['timeZone'] = 'UTC';
$data['end'] = array();
$data['end']['dateTime'] = $endStr;
$data['end']['timeZone'] = 'UTC';

echo 'subject: ' . $subject . '<br>';
echo 'body: ' . $body . '<br>';
echo 'start: ' . $startStr . '<br>';
echo 'end: ' . $endStr . '<br>';

$token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$request = $graph->createRequest("post", '/me/calendar');
$request->attachBody($data);
$response = $request->execute();
```

When I change the createRequest to be

```
$request = $graph->createRequest("post", '/xxxx/calendar');
```

where xxxx is another user name, I am getting the following response

```
400 Bad Request
```

The permissions I am using to login are

```
profile openid email User.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
```

What else do I need to do in order to send items to another users calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [missing the permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#calendars-permissions) to act on another user's calendar. You have a few ways that you can do this:

1. You can send a meeting invite to the user. This will work for most users since the default behavior is for meeting invites to automatically be added to a user's calendar. Just create a meeting with the target user as an attendee.
2. Since you have Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared, the target user needs to share their calendar with you.
3. Have application permissions be set for Calendar.ReadWrite.

The choice of which one is most appropriate depends on the requirements, how the application is structured, and who is the actor that is making a change.

Comment: Thanks Michael, If I get the admin to consent to it, it will allow all users (they are in a group policy) to Read and Write to calendars ?

Comment: Only if you're using Application instead of Delegated scopes. In other words, your app needs to obtain a token using the OAuth Client Credentials grant rather than the Authorization Code grant.